# Should "Story" and "Campaign-development" be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of now [story](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) is tagged in 26 questions with no wiki entry for it. [campaign-development](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign-development) has 105 tagged questions and has a short yet, decent wiki entry:

> Writing, managing, and expanding campaigns.

I feel that all the questions tagged **Story** could just as easily be tagged **campaign-development** and that its redundant to have **Story** as a tag at all. The **Campaign-development** tag could be reworded more explicitly to include story development within a campaign and could absorb all questions currently tagged **Story**. Please chime in with your thoughts.

Comment: @waxeagle nice, didn't realize there was a tag format I could pull on when writing questions, answers, and whatnot. good to know.

Comment: Those are in no way synonymous.

Comment: @mxyzplk The kind of questions asked in [tag:story] largely seemed to match a subset of those asked under [tag:campaign-development].

Comment: they are not synonymous but campaign development does involve story. the two are inexorably bound to each other.

Comment: Okay, I misused synonymous, that is my fault, but Novian gets at what I am trying to communicate which is that [tag:story] questions can be contained within [tag:campaign-development] questions without any harm to the story questions.

Comment: Question has been edited to fit my intent, removed mention of synonym.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for the edit, I had that in there as a copy while I was editing in case I changed it too much and then left the dupe of the question in after the fact by accident.

Answer (score 6):

No. "Campaign" and "story" are not interchangeable, and neither is necessarily a subset of the other. Not all campaigns have a plot, and not all plots are the length of a campaign.

I do (personally) think that [story](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) is not a very good tag, but it's not a *problem* tag so sleeping dogs get to lie undisturbed.

Comment: +1 to me they have separate implications, only crossing over sometimes - and most tags cross over sometimes.